# Transform JSONArray into array of JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have JSONArray as below :

```
[["title","details"],["abc","xyz"],["abc2","xyz2"]]
```

How to transform into Array of JSONObject as below using Java /JavaScript?

```
[ { 'title': abc,  'details':xyz,}, {'title': abc2, 'details':xyz2}]
```

Comment: Is it really [java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) you want to use???

Comment: Yes using existing Java library form `org.json` or jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is no java library!!!1!11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code was modified from the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117916/merge-keys-array-and-values-array-into-an-object-in-javascript) to allow multiple arrays of values to be passed.

```
function makeObject(keys, array) {
    var output = [];
    for (var o = 0; o < array.length; o++) {
        var object = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < array[o].length; i ++ ) {
         object[keys[i]] = array[o][i];
        }
        output.push(object);
    }
    return output;
}

// input array
var array = [["title","details"],["abc","xyz"],["abc2","xyz2"]];    

// extract keys leaving only values in array
var keys = array.shift();

// build object
var output = makeObject(keys, array);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u54tT/1/

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful answer. I was looking around for JQuery implementation and didn't notice that JS still able to transform into json.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this for now. Still looking for build in function or concrete implementation on this.

```
String inputStr = "[[\"title\",\"details\"],[\"abc\",\"xyz\"],[\"abc2\",\"xyz2\"]]";

try {
    JSONArray inputArray = new JSONArray(inputStr);
    JSONArray outputArray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray inArr = inputArray.getJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < inArr.length(); j++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                outputArray.put(new JSONObject().put(
                        inputArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(j), inArr.get(j)));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("outputArray = " + outputArray.toString());
} catch (JSONException jse) {
    System.out.println("jse = " + jse.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
outputArray = [{"title":"abc"},{"details":"xyz"},{"title":"abc2"},{"details":"xyz2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
jQuery.parseJSON( json ) Returns: Object
```

Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I'm looking to parse array. Please refer to question above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the task correctly there no method that will this job since it seems to be a bit non-trivial case. So you should write your own transformation..