# How to transform a JsonArray to JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I have a json array like this :

```
[{"myid":"123","post":"harry"},{"myid":"456":"ramon"}]
```

I would like to make a JSONObject out of it. I'm used to JSONArray like this:

```
`{"myid":"123","post":"harry"}`
```

or

```
{"myid":"123","post":[str1, str2]}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform JSONArray into array of JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912131/transform-jsonarray-into-array-of-jsonobject)

Comment: Two problems with this Question: 1) You haven't said how you would make a single object out of the two objects in that array. 2) You seem to be asking us to code it for you.  That is not an acceptable form of Question on SO.  We are here to help programmers, not to do their jobs for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Json object
String json = '{"myid":"123","post":"harry"}';
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);
String id = jobj.getString("myid");

//Json Array
String json = '[{"myid":"123","post":"harry"},{"myid":"456":"ramon"}]';
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(json);
JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(0);
String id = jobj.getString("myid");
```

You will have to wrap it in a `try catch` to make sure to catch exceptions like json strings that cant be parsed and other errors.