# Transform array of keys and array of values into array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

My question is quite similar to this one: [Merge keys array and values array into an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117916/merge-keys-array-and-values-array-into-an-object-in-javascript)

However, I don't seem to find the solution for my example. If I have these two arrays:

```js
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const values = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [10, 20, 30],
];
```

How do I combine them into an array of objects, such that would be the expected result?

```js
[
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    z: 2,
  },
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 20,
    z: 30,
  },
]
```

Comment: And the problem is? Just do the steps from the linked question `values.length` times (`values.reduce(<magic>)`)

Comment: `values.map(x => x.reduce((a,c,i) => (a[keys[i]] = c, a), {})` would be my very quick attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()` for this:

```js
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const values = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [10, 20, 30],
];

const res = values.map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[keys[index]] = curr

  return acc;
}, {x: null, y: null, z: null}));

console.log(res);
```

Or you can also do it without `reduce()` like so:

```js
const res = values.map(arr => ({
  [keys[0]]: arr[0],
  [keys[1]]: arr[1],
  [keys[2]]: arr[2]
}));
```

Comment: (you might want to increment the index in the map, otherwise it will be the same key/value repeated three times)

Answer (score 1):

Cycle through the value arrays and create an object for each, then cycle through the values within those arrays and use the keys array as the keys.

```js
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const values = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [10, 20, 30],
];

const output = [];
values.forEach((v, i) => {
  output[i] = {}; // create objects for each of the value arrays
  v.forEach((w, j) => {
    output[i][keys[j]] = w; // use the correct keys with each of the values
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

As comments have also pointed out, this can be done with `Array.reduce`:

```js
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const values = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [10, 20, 30],
];

const output = values.map(x => { // for each of the values arrays
  return x.reduce((a, c, i) => { // take its values
    a[keys[i]] = c // map them to an object property one by one
    return a; // put them together in the same object.
  }, {});
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const values = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [10, 20, 30],
];


function toObject(keys, values) {
    let final = []
     for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
         let result = {};
         for(let j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
             result[keys[j]] = values[i][j];
            
         }
        final.push(result)
     }
    return final 
    console.log(final)
     
 }
 
 toObject(keys,values )
```

it will work